# youtube api - arabic text not showing

Tags: php, youtube-api

The problem is that when I use Youtube API to get a video (ex. video entry, feed, etc) it dose not show correct. for example:

> الوسمي - المكتوب

appears like this

> Ø§Ù„ÙˆØ³Ù…ÙŠ - Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙƒØªÙˆØ¨

What is the cause of this, although english titles and content appears correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with UTF-8 charset on your page:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
echo $video_title;
```

---

Using byte values from treating the weird characters you gave as windows cp1252:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$str = "\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x88\xd8\xb3\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\x20\x2d\x20\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd9\x85\xd9\x83\xd8\xaa\xd9\x88\xd8\xa8";

echo $str; //الوسمي - المكتوب  if the charset=UTF-8 is working
```

You can use the above code to always test if you are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try fetching any content from

in PHP :urlencode()

In js:encodeUriComponent()

and reverse is

In php : urldecode()

IN js:decodeUriComponent()

Comment: Thanks, i used @ Esailija 's answer because i just typed it in my header.php page and it was implemented on the whole site

Comment: great then you must accept @Esailija's answer to acknowledge him

Comment: yup i was going to do so before you anserd but I've been told i should wait 5 mints to scent an answer , so now i did

Comment: yeah, from your answer i know that u may have more knolage than  me but i said maybe we can cooperate on developing something, nice to meet ya

Comment: more knowledge we share with others ,more we get .nice to meet you too . we will keep in touch through other answers...next tym i think you are going to answer my question..... ;)

Comment: i will look forward to do so :)